# Node.js: How to get filename where function was required from within a module?

Tags: node.js, module, console, require

I'm trying to get the original filename from where a module's function has been required from. I know you can use `__filename` to get the current file, but I want to get the original file.

For example a simple module I have would be

**module.js**

```
module.exports(function() {
   return {
     print : function(message) {
        console.log(__filename + ' ' + message);
     };
   }
});
```

**app.js**

```
var module = require('./module')();
module.print('hello');
```

What ends up happening is it will print `module.js hello` but I really want to see `app.js hello`.

I was exploring ways to get it and I know you can use `console.trace` to see the stack of calls but I can't parse it to do what I want.

Right now I've worked about it by making the `print` function take in another parameter and you simply pass `__filename` from within `app.js` but I kind of want to find a solution where I don't have to do this.

Comment: And what's wrong with passing it in to the module, as in `var module = require('./module')(__filename);`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it, I just wanted to know if it was possible. If it's not possible, that's a perfectly okay answer as well.

Comment: @aug Did my answer solve your dilemma?

Comment: @Swivel hey thanks for following up! Wow it does! Sorry I never saw it :) accepting

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Getting Parent Module

You can do this by using [`module.parent`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) , then resolving the [`filename`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) property like so:

#### module.js

```
module.exports(function() {
   return {
     print : function(message) {
        console.log(module.parent.filename + ' ' + message);
     };
   }
});
```

#### app.js

```
var module = require('./module')();
module.print('hello');
```

#### Output:

```
/path/to/app.js hello
```

Which is almost what you're asking for.

## Qualifying The Solution

This solution provides you with a fully qualified path, but you get the filename by splitting the path by its delimiter.

```
var parentModFilename = module.parent.filename.split(/\\|\//).pop()
```

Which would then give you `"/app.js"` in `parentModFilename`.

Comment: Avoid manipulating paths directly. Use the [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path) module to extract information from paths in a platform agnostic way.

Comment: Note that `module.parent` will give you the module that *first* required `module.js`, so if another module required `module.js` before `app.js`, you will get that module's name, rather than `app.js`. Also `module.parent` is now [deprecated](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#moduleparent).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `require.resolve(moduleName)` to get the full path to the file. `path.basename` can strip the parent directories. So in your example:

```
var path = require("path");
var module = require('./module')();
process.stdout.write(path.basename(require.resolve('./module') + " ");
module.print('hello');
```