# NodeJS get name of file that includes the current file

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I have a file `running.js` that includes another file `dependency.js`, what code in `dependency.js` will return the name of the including file `running.js`?

If I do `path.basename(__filename)` within dependency.js it returns 'dependency.js' not 'running.js'.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643041/how-can-i-detect-the-entry-file-in-node-js don't want to flag as dupe because I'm not 100% this is what you're looking for, but `require.main.filename` seems to be what you're after

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/32001075/3284355

Comment: That returns the test runner that starts everything up. I need the file that directly includes the current one.

Comment: Another possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227489/how-can-one-get-the-file-path-of-the-caller-function-in-node-js. The far simpler method would be to pass the caller filename as an argument to the module.